# Get JSON keys using Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have a MYSQL table that consists of one attribute/field, `myjson` and it looks like,

```
+----------------------------------+
| myjson                           |
+----------------------------------+
| {"key1":22}                      |
| {"key2":34}                      |
| {"key2":304}                     |
| {}                               |
| {"key3":304}                     |
| {"key4":164}                     |
+----------------------------------+
```

How can I retrive the `keys` using **Django ORM** ? (in Python it's `my_dict.keys()`)

**Expected Output**
mysql version

```
+----------------------------------+
| myjson_keys                      |
+----------------------------------+
| key1                             |
| key2                             |
| key3                             |
| key4                             |
+----------------------------------+
```

**NOTE**: I'm using `Djano 1.9.13` and  `MySQL Community Server 5.7.21`

Comment: and what kind of field is that in Django and in MySQL?

Comment: I think its `CharField()` , using this package [django-jsonfield](https://github.com/dmkoch/django-jsonfield)

Comment: Django ORM per se won't help you with this if it's a char field. You can either call a database function  using Django ORM (if mysql has something like `Keys(myjson)`) or you can see if the package django-jsonfield could give you directly the json converted to dict, so you could do `keys`. 
But if it's one row one {attr: value}, I doubt there is a way in any library, then you should consider changing the schema so that there is instead the json column one VARCHAR column key and another INTEGER value.